# SOLVED - How to set discount price in Amazon Listing API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

By using Listing API, I work to offer exist product in Amazon with LISTING_OFFER_ONLY. But I failing unsuccesfully discount_price. I always have error message : An internal error has occurred. Try again.
purchasable_offer object is this:

```
"purchasable_offer": [
            {
                "currency": "TRY",
                "discounted_price": [
                    {
                        "schedule": [
                            {
                                "value_with_tax": "9000.0",
                                "end_date": "2024-03-12",
                                "start_date": "2024-03-04"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "our_price": [
                    {
                        "schedule": [
                            {
                                "value_with_tax": "9999.0"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

and my error message:

```
{
    "sku": "Test-123-TESTTESTTEST",
    "status": "INVALID",
    "submissionId": "b4f2XXX...",
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "4000000",
            "message": "An internal error has occurred. Try again.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "categories": []
        }
    ]
}
```

How to fix this problem?
How to need to send purchasable_offer?

**Solution:
The problem is caused by incorrect field spelling in my body content.
start_date -> start_at
end_date -> end_at**

```
"purchasable_offer": [ { "currency": "TRY", "discounted_price": [ { "schedule": [ { "value_with_tax": "9000.0", "end_at": "2024-03-12", "start_at": "2024-03-04" } ] } ], "our_price": [ { "schedule": [ { "value_with_tax": "9999.0" } ] } ] } ]
```

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, instead of adding it to the question.

Comment: @MarkB thank you. I was looking at how to do it. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The problem is caused by incorrect field spelling in my body content.
start_date -> start_at
end_date -> end_at

Like this:

```
"purchasable_offer": [ { "currency": "TRY", "discounted_price": [ { "schedule": [ { "value_with_tax": "9000.0", "end_at": "2024-03-12", "start_at": "2024-03-04" } ] } ], "our_price": [ { "schedule": [ { "value_with_tax": "9999.0" } ] } ] } ]
```